# Scrapy pipeline doesn't runs

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following spider:

```
class WebSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "web"
    allowed_domains = ["www.web.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.web.com/page/"]
    custom_settings = {
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
            "models.pipelines.ModelsPipeline": 1,
            "models.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline": 2,
        },
        "IMAGES_STORE": get_project_settings().get("FILES_STORE"),
    }

def parse_models(self, response):
    ...
    yield WebItem(image_urls=[img_url], images=[name], name=name, collection="web")


class WebItem(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    collection = scrapy.Field()
```

the MongoDBPipeline works alwais with the followings configurations

```
"ITEM_PIPELINES": {
    "models.pipelines.ModelsPipeline": 1,
    "models.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline": 2,
}

"ITEM_PIPELINES": {
    "models.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline": 2,
}
```

but the ModelsPipeline never runs in any of the following configurations

```
"ITEM_PIPELINES": {
    "models.pipelines.ModelsPipeline": 1,
    "models.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline": 2,
}

"ITEM_PIPELINES": {
    "models.pipelines.ModelsPipeline": 1,
}
```

The `ModelsPipeline` is in the same file that `MongoDBPipeline` and the code is the following:

```
class ModelsPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        pdb.set_trace()
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        pdb.set_trace()
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        adapter['image_paths'] = image_paths
        return item
```

but never executes get_media_requests or item_completed

the code is the same that the doc https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html

What is wrong and what scrapy doesn't runs the `ModelsPipeline`

**EDIT**

Scrapy version is 2.8.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Media pipelines, you need to have all the appropriate settings populated in order for them to work.

In your case the ModelsPipeline is inheriting from the ImagesPipeline, so you must fulfill all of the ImagesPipeline requirements.

Those include:

1. `IMAGES_STORE` setting ... not `FILES_STORE`
2. The scrapy item needs to have the appropriate fields
3. You can set those fields custom using the

   ```
   IMAGES_URLS_FIELD = 'field_name_for_your_images_urls'
   IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD = 'field_name_for_your_processed_images'
   ```
4. Or you can use the default fields, or both:

   ```
   import scrapy

   class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
       # ... other item fields ...
       image_urls = scrapy.Field()
       images = scrapy.Field()
   ```

There are several other optional settings that need to be properly set if you choose to use them, and you must make sure that your `IMAGES_STORE` path already exists.

Comment: I replaced IMAGEs_STORE and added the two fields image_urls and images, but nothing, the IMAGES_STORE is a folder that exists.

Comment: @Tlaloc-ES  try explicitly setting the `IMAGES_STORE ` in your custom settings instead of relying on get_project_settings...  also try explicitly setting the IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD and other settings.  If none of that works then try adding some print statements in the pipeline and see you can see them in the log output

Comment: @Tlaloc-ES  You also need to have pillow installed in order to use the image pipeline... that might be your issue  `pip install pillow`